# MYSQL JOIN QUERY for friendship table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following two tables

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
 id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE friends (
 id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 account_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 friend_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

I established a JOIN query as such:

```
SELECT accounts.name, accounts.id, friends.account_id FROM accounts
RIGHT JOIN friends ON accounts.id = friends.account_id
ORDER BY accounts.name LIMIT 10;
```

It will look something like:

Mike Fenway | 1 | 3 |

Jim Morison | 3 | 1 |

The question is how do I display the friends name so that the result appear as such:

Mike Fenway | 1 | Jim Morison | 3 |

Jim Morison | 3 | Mike Fenway | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform a further join to get the friend data. I have used `LEFT JOIN` to always return the account, even if there are no friends. An `INNER JOIN` would return only accounts that have friends and omit those which do not.

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, ACC.id `friendId`, ACC.name `friendName`
FROM accounts A
LEFT JOIN friends F ON A.id = F.account_id
LEFT JOIN accounts ACC ON F.friend_id = ACC.id
ORDER BY A.name LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    MainAccount.Name as OwnerName,
    MainAccount.ID as OwnerID,
    COALESCE(AnotherMain.Name, '') as FriendName
    COALESCE(Friends.ID, '')  as FriendID
FROM
    Accounts as MainAccount 
        LEFT JOIN Friends ON
            MainAccount.ID = Friends.ID
        LEFT JOIN Accounts as AnotherMain ON
            Friends.ID = AnotherMain.ID
ORDER BY MainAccount.Name LIMIT 10
```